# weighted summation of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $u_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n\geq 1} u_n$ converges. Take  $x_n$ a decreasing sequence of positive numbers that converges to $0$ when  $n$ tends to $+\infty$. I want to show that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n-x_{n+1})\Sigma_{k=1}^n u_k/x_k.$$
I tried to use the generalized Cesaro's lemma but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

A standard fact  (Method of partial summation) says $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kx_k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k(x_k-x_{k+1})$ where $b_k=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k$. (In our case convergence is not a problem. To show that this equality holds just see what the coefficient of each $x_k$ is on either side).

All you have to do now is put $a_k=\frac {u_k} {x_k}$.